# multiple CSS classes, how they work and WHY do it this way?

Tags: html, css, user-experience

I'm a programmer not a CSS dude and like most programmers haven't spent too much time trying to understand the effects of CSS.  There has always been an UX person to handle.  But as I get more experienced I am digging CSS and the UX.  So my question is this:

What I understand:

```
<div class="AClassName" >
</div>
```

I understand how this relates to the .css file and what will happen.

What I don't understand:

```
<div class="AClassName andAnother1 andAnother2">
</div>
```

I'm hoping there is a simple explanation.

Comment: what exactly you don't understand? an element may have more than one class applied

Comment: exactly that..  is the first class more dominant than any subsequent class?  is it just a hybrid?

Comment: I feel this is just basic CSS. There are a ton of websites teaching CSS basics, please use [**Google**](http://www.google.com) and find them.

Comment: Let me suppose i have two `div's` like this

    <div class='a b'></div>
    <div class='a c'></div>

the properties of `a` are being shared by both the `divs`.

Comment: _“is the first class more dominant than any subsequent class?”_ – no, the sequence of the class names in the `class` attribute does not matter. What matters, is the order and specifity of the rules in the stylesheet.

Comment: there's no dominance on the order defined in the markup. You choose the dominance through the css cascade (or specificity) only

Comment: @green Wizard: really that's it?  that's a perfect example.  do the css elements b and c have to "under" a or are they not dependent on a at all?

Comment: On their own, those classes are equal. But in the `CSS` we can override them, `.andAnother1 { background:red; }`, and `.andAnother2: background:blue !important;`, because we have an `!important` rule, then the background will be blue.

Comment: ok, thanks.  that is pretty simple.

Comment: I would recommend you to use Google Chrome's Inspector tool to inspect HTML elements and look at their applied styling rules. The Inspector is a terrific tool to interactively see what is applied to what.

Comment: It's times like this I miss the "Lacks a minimal understanding of the problem" close reason. Anyone have the meta.SO discussion for why it was removed?

Comment: You ask a question like this and **I'm** the moron?

Comment: lol, i write server software... css is not my bag.  And I would own you when it comes to resume and accomplishments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example:

```
<div class="positionClass contentClass decorClass">
    Lorem textum
</div>
```

`.positionClass`: here any position properties could be applyed, 4example absolute/fixed position, display properties, margin/negative margin.

`.contentClass` : here we can add styles to text: line-height, font-size and so on.

And the last one for some decoration elements.

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: perfect explanation.  That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

CSS works from top to bottom - meaning the styling you add last will override any previous styles.

For instance if I take a button with a `class="btn"` and style `btn` to be `background-color:black;` all my buttons will be black but I want to have a button that's red, then I add `class="btn btnCustom"` or `class="btnCustom btn"` and style btnCustom to have a `background-color:red` it will override that button's style only.

See JS fiddle bellow:
http://jsfiddle.net/udru2/

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one class for same element in any order. Order is important in .css file itself. Imagine, that all classes are added in one array and all keys (like width, height..) are overridden by any new entry by that key (reading file from top to bottom).

Answer (score 1):

Let me suppose i have two `div's` like this

```
<div class='make-red capitalize'>abcd</div>
<div class='make-green make-center'>askhdj</div>
```

and the `css` as follows

```
.make-red{
color:red;
}

.capitalize{
text-transform:uppercase;
}

.make-green{
color:green;
}

.make-center{
text-align:cneter;
}
```

In a big page where we use loots of `divs` which are to be styled, this kind of approach helps you. This is just a single use which can be shared.